Randomly Split a Graph into Mini Graphs
I have this graph network in R:
library(igraph)
n_rows <- 10
n_cols <- 5
g <- make_lattice(dimvector = c(n_cols, n_rows))

layout <- layout_on_grid(g, width = n_cols)

n_nodes <- vcount(g)
node_colors <- rep("white", n_nodes)

for (row in 0:(n_rows-1)) {
    start_index <- row * n_cols + 1
    node_colors[start_index:(start_index+2)] <- "orange"  
    node_colors[(start_index+3):(start_index+4)] <- "purple"    
}

node_labels <- 1:n_nodes

plot(g, 
     layout = layout, 
     vertex.color = node_colors,
     vertex.label = node_labels,
     vertex.label.color = "black",
     vertex.size = 15,
     edge.color = "gray",
     main = "Rectangular Undirected Network")


I am trying to write a function which randomly breaks this network into 5 connected subgraphs (i.e. mini graphs) such that each node appears exactly once.
I think in theory, this should not be too difficult to do. I would need to randomly identify a node, randomly decide how many neighbors to include, select those neighbors and remove them from the graph .... and restart this process on the remaining graph. Of course, some additional details would need to be specified, e.g. if the random number specified exceed the number of remaining nodes then use a max function, BFS would need to be used to select the nodes, etc.
Here was my first attempt at writing the code:
get_connected_subgraph <- function(graph, available_nodes, min_nodes = 5, max_nodes = 15) {
    if (length(available_nodes) == 0) return(NULL)
    
    start_node <- sample(available_nodes, 1)
    
    bfs_result <- bfs(graph, root = start_node, unreachable = FALSE, order = TRUE, rank = TRUE, father = TRUE)
    
    bfs_order <- intersect(bfs_result$order, available_nodes)
    
    n_subgraph_nodes <- min(sample(min_nodes:max_nodes, 1), length(bfs_order))
    
    subgraph_nodes <- bfs_order[1:n_subgraph_nodes]
    
    return(subgraph_nodes)
}

create_5_subgraphs <- function(graph) {
    available_nodes <- V(graph)
    subgraphs <- list()
    
    for (i in 1:5) {
        subgraph_nodes <- get_connected_subgraph(graph, available_nodes)
        if (is.null(subgraph_nodes)) break
        
        subgraphs[[i]] <- subgraph_nodes
        available_nodes <- setdiff(available_nodes, subgraph_nodes)
    }
    
    return(subgraphs)
}

set.seed(42) 
subgraphs <- create_5_subgraphs(g)

subgraph_colors <- c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple")

node_subgraph_colors <- rep("lightgray", vcount(g))
for (i in 1:length(subgraphs)) {
    node_subgraph_colors[subgraphs[[i]]] <- subgraph_colors[i]
}

edge_subgraph_colors <- rep("lightgray", ecount(g))
for (i in 1:length(subgraphs)) {
    subgraph_edges <- E(g)[.inc(subgraphs[[i]])]
    edge_subgraph_colors[subgraph_edges] <- subgraph_colors[i]
}

plot(g, 
     layout = layout,
     vertex.color = node_subgraph_colors,
     vertex.label = node_labels,
     vertex.label.color = "black",
     vertex.size = 15,
     edge.color = edge_subgraph_colors,
     edge.width = 2,
     main = "Network with 5 Separate Connected Subgraphs")


The above result looks almost correct, but the yellow nodes (e.g. 29) appears to be violating the connectivity.
Any pointers on how to fix this?

I wrote some optional code to compare the before/after:
node_info <- data.frame(
    Node_Index = 1:vcount(g),
    Original_Color = node_colors,
    New_Color = node_subgraph_colors
)

get_subgraph_number <- function(node) {
    subgraph_num <- which(sapply(subgraphs, function(x) node %in% x))
    if (length(subgraph_num) == 0) return(NA)
    return(subgraph_num)
}

node_info$Subgraph_Number <- sapply(node_info$Node_Index, get_subgraph_number)

head(node_info)


To complement jblood94's amazing answer, here is a quick plotting function that works with jblood94's answer:
library(igraph)
library(data.table)

f <- function(g, n) {
    m <- length(g)
    dt <- setDT(as_data_frame(g))
    dt <- rbindlist(list(dt, dt[,.(from = to, to = from)]))
    dt[,group := 0L]
    used <- logical(m)
    s <- sample(m, n)
    used[s] <- TRUE
    m <- m - n
    dt[from %in% s, group := .GRP, from]
    
    while (m) {
        dt2 <- unique(
            dt[group != 0L & !used[to], .(grow = to, onto = group)][sample(.N)],
            by = "grow"
        )
        dt[dt2, on = .(from = grow), group := onto]
        used[dt2[[1]]] <- TRUE
        m <- m - nrow(dt2)
    }
    
    unique(dt[,to := NULL])[,.(vertices = .(from)), group]
}


plot_multiple_subgraphs <- function(n_plots = 25, n_rows = 10, n_cols = 5, n_subgraphs = 5) {
    g <- make_lattice(dimvector = c(n_cols, n_rows))
    layout <- layout_on_grid(g, width = n_cols)
    n_nodes <- vcount(g)
    
    color_palette <- c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple")
    
    par(mfrow = c(5, 5), mar = c(0.5, 0.5, 2, 0.5))
    
    for (i in 1:n_plots) {
        subgraphs <- f(g, n_subgraphs)
        
        node_colors <- rep("white", n_nodes)
        
        for (j in 1:nrow(subgraphs)) {
            nodes <- unlist(subgraphs$vertices[j])
            node_colors[nodes] <- color_palette[j]
        }
        
        plot(g, 
             layout = layout, 
             vertex.color = node_colors,
             vertex.label = NA,  
             vertex.size = 15,   
             edge.color = "gray",
             edge.width = 0.5,  
             main = paste("Partition", i),  
             cex.main = 0.8)     
    }
}

plot_multiple_subgraphs()



If you don't need the subgraph size constraints you can just delete edges until count_components(g_sub) == 5. I think your problem is that you're doing BFS on the original graph and taking the intersection with remaining nodes. You might first create a new graph that only has available vertices and BFS that.

@n1000: thank you so much! by size constraint, you mean ... minimum size of each subgraph?

Yes. I took min_nodes=5 to be a restriction on the allowed subgraph partitions.

Does this mimic the minimal code to reproduce your issue?

Here's a function that randomly selects n vertices from the graph g as the initial subgraph member for each of n groups, then iteratively "grows" each group until all the vertices are in a subgraph.
library(data.table)

f <- function(g, n) {
  m <- length(g)
  dt <- setDT(as_data_frame(g))
  dt <- rbindlist(list(dt, dt[,.(from = to, to = from)]))
  dt[,group := 0L]
  used <- logical(m)
  s <- sample(m, n)
  used[s] <- TRUE
  m <- m - n
  dt[from %in% s, group := .GRP, from]
  
  while (m) {
    dt2 <- unique(
      dt[group != 0L & !used[to], .(grow = to, onto = group)][sample(.N)],
      by = "grow"
    )
    dt[dt2, on = .(from = grow), group := onto]
    used[dt2[[1]]] <- TRUE
    m <- m - nrow(dt2)
  }
  
  unique(dt[,to := NULL])[,.(vertices = .(from), .N), group]
}

Demonstrating on the OP's graph:
set.seed(907044864)
f(g, 5L)
#>    group              vertices     N
#>    <int>                <list> <int>
#> 1:     1       1,2,3,6,7,8,...     9
#> 2:     2  4, 5, 9,10,13,14,...    13
#> 3:     3 21,22,26,27,31,36,...     9
#> 4:     4 23,28,29,32,33,38,...    10
#> 5:     5 30,34,35,39,40,44,...     9

Note: during the iterations, if multiple groups try to "grow into" the same vertex, the winning group is selected randomly. This is done with [sample(.N)] after all the candidate growths are found with dt[group != 0L & !used[to], .(grow = to, onto = group)].

Performance check
Testing performance on partitioning a 100-by-100 grid into 10 groups:
system.time(dt <- f(make_lattice(c(100, 100)), 10))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.16    0.02    0.17
dt
#>     group                          vertices     N
#>     <int>                            <list> <int>
#>  1:     4                   1,2,3,4,5,6,...  2329
#>  2:     2             43,44,45,46,47,48,...  1093
#>  3:     1             87,88,89,90,91,92,...    99
#>  4:     3       695,696,697,795,796,797,...   380
#>  5:     5 1551,1552,1553,1554,1650,1651,...  1363
#>  6:     6 3171,3172,3173,3174,3175,3176,...  1048
#>  7:     7 5921,5922,5923,5924,5925,5926,...  2377
#>  8:     8 6169,6171,6269,6270,6271,6272,...   339
#>  9:     9 6475,6575,6576,6675,6676,6677,...   264
#> 10:    10 7980,7981,7982,7983,7984,7985,...   708


thank you so much! I posted a visualization code as an extra

Nice! I wanted to see what the partitions were looking like, but didn't feel like coding up the visualization.

@ jblood94: I tried to adapt your code for this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79185801/simulating-random-numbers-between-ranges-that-sum-to-a-constant Can you please look if you have time?

With igraph::voronoi_cells(g, ...)$membership:
library(igraph, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

n_rows <- 10
n_cols <- 5

g <- make_lattice(dimvector = c(n_cols, n_rows))

# Voronoi partitioning
set.seed(42)
V(g)$sub <- voronoi_cells(g, sample(V(g), 5), tiebreaker = "first")$membership

# summary
V(g)$names <- V(g)
as_data_frame(g, what = "vertices") |> 
  dplyr::summarise(names = list(names), size = lengths(names), .by = sub)
#>   sub                                                  names size
#> 1   2                              1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 12, 16    8
#> 2   4                             4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15    8
#> 3   1 17, 21, 22, 26, 27, 28, 31, 32, 33, 36, 37, 38, 41, 42   14
#> 4   3                     18, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25, 29, 30, 35    9
#> 5   0             34, 39, 40, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50   11

withr::with_par(
  list(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0)),
  plot(g, 
       layout = layout_on_grid(g, width = n_cols), 
       # membership IDs are 0-based, hence +1 to subset colors
       vertex.color = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple")[V(g)$sub + 1],
       vertex.label.color = "black",
       vertex.size = 15,
       edge.color = "gray")
)


Created on 2024-09-13 with reprex v2.1.1

@margsul: thank you! I thought voroni diagrams are deterministic ?

With a constant generator vector (order plays a role too) and non-random tiebreaker they are (random might not play nice with small graphs) . Do you need it to be random when called with the same sequence of nodes?

thank you for your reply! sorry for the delay, I must have missed your message. I think the answer above meets my needs - currently I am trying to further adapt it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79185801/simulating-random-numbers-between-ranges-that-sum-to-a-constant . do you have any ideas about this one?

I would say that your bfs is a good approach to start from, and you can use bfs like below
nrsubg <- 5
gg <- g <- g %>%
  set_vertex_attr("name", value = seq.int(vcount(.)))
szsubg <- diff(sort(c(0, vcount(g), sample(vcount(g) - 1, nrsubg - 1))))
vlst <- setNames(vector("list", nrsubg), seq.int(nrsubg))
for (i in seq_along(szsubg)) {
  vlst[[i]] <- names(head(bfs(gg, sample(V(gg)[which.min(degree(gg))], 1))$order, szsubg[i]))
  gg <- induced_subgraph(gg, V(gg)[!names(V(gg)) %in% vlst[[i]]])
}
g %>%
  set_vertex_attr("color", value = with(stack(vlst), ind[match(names(V(.)), values)])) 

where the size of each connected "mini graph" is random.
visualization
g %>% 
  plot(
    layout = layout,
    vertex.label = V(.)$name,
    vertex.label.color = "black",
    vertex.size = 15,
    edge.color = "gray",
    main = "Rectangular Undirected Network"
  )

shows something like below for example




Thank you so much for this cool answer! Do you have any idea about this one here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78971812/fading-colors-in-a-graph
