Merging a Data Frame to each element in a List?
I have the following graph:
library(igraph)
n_rows <- 10
n_cols <- 5
g <- make_lattice(dimvector = c(n_cols, n_rows))

layout <- layout_on_grid(g, width = n_cols)

n_nodes <- vcount(g)
node_colors <- rep("white", n_nodes)

for (row in 0:(n_rows-1)) {
    start_index <- row * n_cols + 1
    node_colors[start_index:(start_index+2)] <- "orange"  
    node_colors[(start_index+3):(start_index+4)] <- "purple"    
}

node_labels <- 1:n_nodes

plot(g, 
     layout = layout, 
     vertex.color = node_colors,
     vertex.label = node_labels,
     vertex.label.color = "black",
     vertex.size = 15,
     edge.color = "gray",
     main = "Rectangular Undirected Network")


In this previous question (Randomly Split a Graph into Mini Graphs), I learned how to break this graph into 5 mini connected subgraphs:
library(data.table)

f <- function(g, n) {
  m <- length(g)
  dt <- setDT(as_data_frame(g))
  dt <- rbindlist(list(dt, dt[,.(from = to, to = from)]))
  dt[,group := 0L]
  used <- logical(m)
  s <- sample(m, n)
  used[s] <- TRUE
  m <- m - n
  dt[from %in% s, group := .GRP, from]
  
  while (m) {
    dt2 <- unique(
      dt[group != 0L & !used[to], .(grow = to, onto = group)][sample(.N)],
      by = "grow"
    )
    dt[dt2, on = .(from = grow), group := onto]
    used[dt2[[1]]] <- TRUE
    m <- m - nrow(dt2)
  }
  
  unique(dt[,to := NULL])[,.(vertices = .(from), .N), group]
}

Question: Suppose I run this function 25 times and store
generate_multiple_subgraphs <- function(n_iterations = 25, n_rows = 10, n_cols = 5, n_subgraphs = 5) {
    g <- make_lattice(dimvector = c(n_cols, n_rows))
    
    subgraph_list <- lapply(1:n_iterations, function(i) {
        f(g, n_subgraphs)
    })
    
    return(subgraph_list)
}
subgraph_sets <- generate_multiple_subgraphs()

In each of these subgraphs, I want to count the percentage of purple nodes (with regards to original colors, i.e. the graph that was purple-orange at the start) in each partition.
I was able to get a summary of the original graph:
original_node_data <- data.frame(
    Node = 1:n_nodes,
    Color = node_colors
)

But I am not sure how to merge this data frame to the list of subgraphs to get a result like this:
   subgraph partition total_nodes purple_nodes percent_purple
        <int>     <int>       <int>        <int>          <num>
  1:        1         1          14            8       57.14286
  2:        1         2          12            2       16.66667
  3:        1         3           4            0        0.00000
  4:        1         4           9            6       66.66667
  5:        1         5          11            4       36.36364
 ---                                                           
121:       25         1          13            3       23.00000
122:       25         2           6            6      100.00000
123:       25         3           9            0        0.00000
124:       25         4           8            5       62.50000
125:       25         5          14            6       42.00000

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Having a look on all your previous questions, I generally suspect you are running an xy-problem.

And its a very interesting article about the xy problem! Some comments I have about this:


in the past, when I post a question without showing what I tried, I am provided with such comments like "stackoverflow is not a code writing service" (e.g. read the first comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78971812/fading-colors-in-a-graph) . And I actually agree with this comment. Before posting a question, I work on the question for roughly a day. When posting a question, I like to show what I have tried already and why it's not working. This serves as both a learning process and demonstrates that I am trying to independently learn before asking for help



I think XY problems are how people learn? In machine learning, we try to fit a model to Y and generalize it to X. In many cases, the model performs badly on both X and Y. My eventual problem that I want to solve is quite complicated for a layperson like myself. I think its better to slowly step towards this problem by working on smaller problems, and then combine the logic from these problems to derive a working solution for the final problem. These are just my thoughts  :)


I do not think that machine learning works like this. Why are you asked to solve it then? Often it is good practice to describe where one starts, what's the final goal, and why one would do this. This helps to avoid xy-problems.

Unfortunately, the answer to "I think XY problems are how people learn?" is no. Please read the web site again.


In each of these subgraphs, I want to count the percentage of purple nodes (with regards to original colors, i.e. the graph that was purple-orange at the start) in each partition.

You might want something along the lines
subgraph_sets = lapply(subgraph_sets, transform, purple = 
                         vapply(vertices, 
                                \(j) round(prop.table(table(node_colors[j]))["purple"] * 100L, 2L), 
                                numeric(1L)))

giving
> head(subgraph_sets)
[[1]]
   group              vertices     N purple
   <int>                <list> <int>  <num>
1:     1       1,2,3,4,5,6,...     9  33.33
2:     2 10,14,15,19,20,25,...     8 100.00
3:     3 11,12,13,16,17,18,...    16  12.50
4:     4 31,32,36,37,41,42,...     9     NA
5:     5 34,39,40,44,45,48,...     8  87.50

[[2]]
   group              vertices     N purple
   <int>                <list> <int>  <num>
1:     1       1,2,3,4,5,6,...    19  52.63
2:     2 11,16,17,21,22,26,...    10     NA
3:     3 23,28,29,33,34,37,...    10  40.00
4:     4        30,35,40,45,50     5 100.00
5:     5     41,42,46,47,48,49     6  16.67

[[3]]
   group              vertices     N purple
   <int>                <list> <int>  <num>
1:     2         1, 6, 7,11,12     5     NA
2:     1       2,3,4,5,8,9,...    11  54.55
3:     3     16,17,21,22,26,27     6     NA
4:     4 19,20,23,24,25,28,...    16  75.00
5:     5 31,32,36,37,41,42,...    12  16.67

[[4]]
   group              vertices     N purple
   <int>                <list> <int>  <num>
1:     1       1,2,3,4,6,7,...    15  13.33
2:     2  5,10,14,15,19,20,...    10  80.00
3:     3 26,27,28,29,30,32,...     9  44.44
4:     4 31,36,37,38,39,40,...     7  28.57
5:     5 42,43,44,45,46,47,...     9  44.44

[[5]]
   group              vertices     N purple
   <int>                <list> <int>  <num>
1:     1       1,2,3,4,5,6,...    10  40.00
2:     2 11,12,13,16,17,21,...     7     NA
3:     3 14,15,18,19,20,24,...     7  85.71
4:     4 23,26,27,28,29,31,...    16  12.50
5:     5 30,35,39,40,44,45,...    10  80.00

[[6]]
   group              vertices     N purple
   <int>                <list> <int>  <num>
1:     1      1, 6,11,16,21,26     6     NA
2:     2  2, 3, 7, 8,12,13,...     9     NA
3:     3  4, 5, 9,10,14,15,...     8 100.00
4:     4 23,24,25,27,28,29,...    14  71.43
5:     5 31,32,36,37,38,41,...    13  15.38

EDIT: Inside transform() you can create more variables; like this example shows for purple.
